# Why is the Redis Insight application creating additional connections?

Tags: redis, database-connection

With no other programs running that might create a Redis client, there is only one client when I list them in the terminal:

```
127.0.0.1:6379> client list
id=152 addr=127.0.0.1:58515 laddr=127.0.0.1:6379
```

When I open Redis Insight (v2) and click the default localhost database on port 6379, the number of clients listed in my terminal increases to 3:

```
127.0.0.1:6379> client list
id=152 addr=127.0.0.1:58515 laddr=127.0.0.1:6379 
id=153 addr=127.0.0.1:58675 laddr=127.0.0.1:6379 
id=154 addr=127.0.0.1:58680 laddr=127.0.0.1:6379
```

I truncated the console output to make it easier to read.

I am new to redis in general and I am using it to build a node.js app. I would like to understand what is going on behind the scenes with these additional connections. It does not affect my node app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RedisInsight V2 creates the following clients:

1. common (1) - always created to get the information for the Overview (for example: CPU, commands/s, or total memory)
2. browser (1) - always created, used to get information to display the list of keys and their values on the Browser page
3. cli (N) - created when you open a CLI (one client per one CLI instance)
4. workbench (1) - created if you run a command in Workbench (one client)
5. profiler (1) - created if you run a profiler (one client)

hope this helps